# How can I safely remove timeout from a script?

Tags: shell, top, timeout, coreutils

I started a script with

```
timeout --signal 2 --kill-after 10 14400
```

and now decided that it should rather run as long as it must,
so I need to remove that timeout from the running script.

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' timeout)
```

tells me there is a timeout process running. Can I safely kill
that process or did my important process become a subprocess and
it would be killed too?

EDIT: Tried killing now. Huge mistake. Killed my script too. So this question is still open: What can I do next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you kill -9 the timeout process then it won't be able to propagate that to the child which should then continue running

Comment: Oh, I would have tried it if I'd have seen that answer one minute earlier. :( But isn't 9 the default signal of kill?

Comment: Okay, tested it again with signal 9. You are right.